# How to comment / document R.java class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javadoc

I am creating an application with Java in Android Studio. I commented and documented my code and and I created a documentation with the integrated JavaDoc tool. **But how can I comment the R.java class** that is generated automatically after building the project? I want to add the sources of images as a comment to the drawables so that the user can see where my pictures are from when reading the JavaDoc documentation.

Comment: You don't mess with R.java file.

Answer (score 3):

The `R.java` class is generated by the build system, and therefore your edits will almost certainly be erased upon the next build of the app.

I'd suggest instead adding documentation to the corresponding `Activity` or `Fragment`'s javadocs if you're following a "[code behind](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303247)" pattern.